# grammar (with plyplus) for a small language for generating python functions

Tags: python, grammar, yacc, ply, python-plyplus

I designed a toy language :

```
# comments
n = 2 #an integer
k = 3.14 # a float
f(x): # a function
    return (x-k)^n

g(z): #another function
    return max(z-2.9, 0.1) # max should be understood

h(x,y: # another function ; note that function can call functions
    return x*g(y)

pointable x # a formal variable 

pointable y # another formal variable

gives h (x @ 3.2, y @  1.9) @ 6.1 # an instruction, the meaning will be clear later

gives f (x @ 1.2) @ 3.1 #another instruction

give # the final instruction
```

The purpose of this language is the following : the previous code, when parsed, is supposed to create the following list :

```
[[1, (f), (1.2), 3.1], [2, (f, h), (3.2, 1.9), 6.1]]
```

There are as many elements as there are `give` instructions.

I have no idea about how to design a grammar for this language. I know that it has to be in a EBNF form because I want to used `plyplus` as I already toyed with it with simple algebraic expressions parsing, but there is a great move from simple algebraic expression directly evaluated and what I intend to do. (Even if I know that formally it is the same.)

(How are treated functions when you have the abstract syntax tree of the above code btw ?)

For information, at the end, from `[[1, (f), (1.2), 3.1], [2, (f, h), (3.2, 1.9), 6.1]]` I want to produce the following python function :

```
def F(X1,X2):
    # code defining f and g "as" defined above
    # ...
    # code using f and g 
    S1 = exp(-3.1)*f(X1/1.2)
    S2 = exp(-6.1)*g(X1/3.2,X2/1.9)
    res = S1 + S2
    return res
```

and I would like to product it is as

```
ast = language_grammar.parse(code_above) #tree
F = tree.generatefunction()
```

I got the python grammar in the `plyplus` form and tried to reduce it (I would still like to having conditions and loops in my language) and adapt, without success, as this is really not my area.

I also feel that I would need in the grammar an algebraic subgrammar using all classical math functions and combining them, but I cannot really give a formal definition to this idea.